# Django-admin.py not working (-bash:django-admin.py: command not found)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, framework-installation

I'm having trouble getting django-admin.py to work... it's in this first location:
/Users/mycomp/bin/  but I think I need it in another location for the terminal to recognize it, no?

Noob, Please help. Thanks!!

```
my-computer:~/Django-1.1.1 mycomp$ sudo ln -s /Users/mycomp/bin/django-admin.py /Users/mycomp/django-1.1.1/django-admin.py
Password:
ln: /Users/mycomp/django-1.1.1/django-admin.py: File exists
my-computer:~/Django-1.1.1 mycomp$ django-admin.py --version
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to export /Users/mycomp/bin to environment variable PATH

for a session

```
export PATH=/Users/mycomp/bin:$PATH
```

for permanent, whenever you use bash

```
echo "export PATH=/Users/mycomp/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Note**: And I think django automatically create executable `django-admin` file in the bin folder (notice there is no extensions .py) when you installed, So you should try `django-admin` only too.

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked... i tried the second one and received the following error:

-bash: export PATH=/Users/mycomp/bin:/Users/mycomp/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin: No such file or directory

Comment: @Diego, Imm, I am not so sure with mac, could you check `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file exists? if yes, you could try to add `export PATH=/Users/mycomp/bin:$PATH` to one of the file by manually editing it. and then do `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` to reflect changes.