# django-admin.py: command not found (bluehost server)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, bluehost

After struggling more than 6 hours, I decided to ask for help.

Mission: To create a project with the help of Django
Tools: Windows Vista, Putty SSH 
Location: Bluehost (www.bluehost.com) Server

**I have already read these topics about the same question:**

1. [-bash: django-admin.py: command not found (Django Installation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059644/bash-django-admin-py-command-not-found-django-installation)
2. [Unable to use django-admin.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112772/unable-to-use-django-admin-py)
3. [Django: When creating a new project, “django-admin.py: command not found” Error pops up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590521/django-when-creating-a-new-project-django-admin-py-command-not-found-error)
4. [django-admin.py: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791368/django-admin-py-command-not-found)
5. [Command not found: django-admin.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250086/command-not-found-django-admin-py)
6. [Django-admin.py not working (-bash:django-admin.py: command not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687704/django-admin-py-not-working-bashdjango-admin-py-command-not-found)

I have installed Python as explained here (Bluehost Help Page): 
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/python-install

## Python 2.7.2 installed and checked, and it looks like:

```
username@domain.com [~/python]# ls
./  ../  Python-2.7.2/  Python-2.7.2.tgz  bin/  include/  lib/  share/
```

the directory **~/python/Python-2.7.2/** looks like this:

```
username@domain.com [~/python/Python-2.7.2]# ls
./                LICENSE          Objects/  build/          pyconfig.h.in
../               Lib/             PC/       config.log      python*
.hg_archival.txt  Mac/             PCbuild/  config.status*  python-gdb.py
.hgtags           Makefile         Parser/   configure*      setup.py
Demo/             Makefile.pre     Python/   configure.in
Doc/              Makefile.pre.in  README    install-sh*
Grammar/          Misc/            RISCOS/   libpython2.7.a
Include/          Modules/         Tools/    pyconfig.h
```

and **~/python/bin/** looks like this:

```
username@domain.com [~/python/bin]# ls
./   2to3*             idle*   python*         python2.7*         smtpd.py*
../  django-admin.py*  pydoc*  python-config@  python2.7-config*
```

## Django 1.5 installed and checked, and it looks like:

```
username@domain.com [~/Django-1.5]# ls
./   AUTHORS  LICENSE      PKG-INFO    build/   docs/    scripts/   setup.py
../  INSTALL  MANIFEST.in  README.rst  django/  extras/  setup.cfg  tests/
```

and **~/Django-1.5/bin/** looks like this:

```
username@domain.com [~/Django-1.5/django/bin]# ls
./   __init__.py        django-2to3.py*   profiling/
../  daily_cleanup.py*  django-admin.py*  unique-messages.py*
```

**Problem: When I try to create my project, I see this error:**

```
username@domain.com [~/www/domain/]# django-admin.py startproject mysite
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
```

Then I have tried again without .py, I see this error:

```
username@domain.com [~/www/domain/]# django-admin.py startproject mysite
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found
```

## ~/.bashrc looks like this:

```
# .bashrc
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH

 #User specific aliases and functions


alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
~
~
```

## ~/bin/ looks like this:

```
username@domain.com [~/bin]# ls
./  ../
```

**So I read a lot about the *PATH*, but I could not make it work. Should I give up?**

Comment: What's your problem? What are you trying to make work? Could you run the site locally before you tried to put it on bluehost?

Comment: @jozzas he can't run `django-admin.py`

Comment: Django is *not* installed. You have copied it to your local directory, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `.bashrc` PATH entry to look like:

```
export PATH=$HOME/Django-1.5/bin/:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH
```

And reload your `.bashrc` by doing:

```
# . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: You could wait for 18 secs :D

Comment: I have changed `.bashrc` as you said (by adding `/django/` between `/Django-1.5/` and `/bin/`) like this: 

`export PATH=$HOME/Django-1.5/django/bin/:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH`
and I no longer see the `command not found` error. 

But now I see this error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home1/expmagco/Django-1.5/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core`

I have searched it again, and found some topics.

Comment: After reading these topics: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core)
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management)

I tried `import django` in Python shell, and I see this: 

`>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django`

In my `python` directory there exists two Python installation, here is the directory: 

`username@domain.com [~/python]# ls
./  ../  Python-2.7.2/  Python-2.7.2.tgz  bin/  include/  lib/  share/`

Comment: And if I check my Python version, I see: 
`username@domain.com [~/python]# python --version
Python 2.6.6`

It should have been Python 2.7.2, but it is Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Actually, in the beginning it seemed Python 2.7.2, with this path:

`export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH` (as explained on Bluehost help page https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/python-install)

but I have changed this with the PATH that @favoretti wrote, and now my Python version seems 2.6.6.

Comment: Solved, I have also added this line:     
`export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH`
And my Python is 2.7.2, I ran this again `django-admin.py startproject mysite`, and it worked.

So at the end. my `.bashrc` seems like this (if someone needs it):

`export PATH=$HOME/Django-1.5/django/bin/:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH`

thanks @favoretti

Answer (score 1):

Add django path to your `$PATH`.

Change you `~/.bashrc` to

```
# .bashrc
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$HOME/Django-1.5/bin/:$PATH

 #User specific aliases and functions


alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
~
~
```